# The function of the %configsetroot% system variable in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, environment-variables

When I checked my PC, the `%configsetroot%` system variable was set to the path: `%SystemRoot%\ConfigSetRoot`

But the weird thing is that the directory as indicated by that path doesn't exist. The ConfigSetRoot folder is missing from my PC. And since it's a system variable, so I assume that it must be somewhat important? Surely, if its a system variable, then it's probably gonna be utilized by the system at some point, right?

What is that variable used for? Does anyone know?

Comment: You probably had an application installed that set the path as a system variable, but it wasn't removed when you uninstalled the application. You can likely remove the variable from your system.

Comment: It seems you have installed the OS from a custom installation media which was prepared for to add files into installator using official way to do it via `$OEM$` folder. But no files were added, so the folder ConfigSetRoot is empty (all files from $OEM$ are unconditionally copied into ConfigSetRoot). Now OS is already installed, so you can freely remove both a folder and a system variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your current Windows version came from an OEM system builder.

The installation may have set up and used this environment variable for
copying files into `%SystemRoot%\ConfigSetRoot`.

After the installation finished, it either cleaned up this folder after itself,
or it had no files to copy. But it forgot to delete the variable `configsetroot`.

You may delete this variable as it is no longer needed.